# Adding li as last element from Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

is there any easy way to add Li from jquery in below structure

```
<div id="ctl00_g_d75240ee_258b_420a_b571_2b97dcda8a66" >

  <ol class="top-menu-bar pull-right">
    <li>
        <a id="ctl00_g_d75240ee_258b_420a_b571_2b97dcda8a66_lbLanguage" href="/ar/">Test</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="ctl00_g_d75240ee_258b_420a_b571_2b97dcda8a66_lbSitemap" href="/en/sitemap">Sitemap</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="ctl00_g_d75240ee_258b_420a_b571_2b97dcda8a66_lbContact" href="/en/contact-us?tab=2">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="ctl00_g_d75240ee_258b_420a_b571_2b97dcda8a66_lbFaq" href="/en/contact-us?tab=3">FAQ</a>
    </li>    
  </ol>

</div>
```

i want  to add below li after FAQ

```
 <li>
            <a id="ctl00_g_d75240ee_258b_420a_b571_2b97dcda8a66_lbFaq" href="/en/contact-us?tab=3">FAQ</a>
          </li>
```

I have tried below but it is addind in all li's

```
$("#ctl00_g_d75240ee_258b_420a_b571_2b97dcda8a66  li").last().html('<li> Menu 5 </li>');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)** to insert after an element

```js
$("#ctl00_g_d75240ee_258b_420a_b571_2b97dcda8a66  li").last().after('<li> Menu 5 </li>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ctl00_g_d75240ee_258b_420a_b571_2b97dcda8a66">

  <ol class="top-menu-bar pull-right">
    <li>
      <a id="ctl00_g_d75240ee_258b_420a_b571_2b97dcda8a66_lbLanguage" href="/ar/">Test</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="ctl00_g_d75240ee_258b_420a_b571_2b97dcda8a66_lbSitemap" href="/en/sitemap">Sitemap</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="ctl00_g_d75240ee_258b_420a_b571_2b97dcda8a66_lbContact" href="/en/contact-us?tab=2">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="ctl00_g_d75240ee_258b_420a_b571_2b97dcda8a66_lbFaq" href="/en/contact-us?tab=3">FAQ</a>
    </li>
  </ol>

</div>
```

or you can use **[`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/)** for appending content

```js
$("#ctl00_g_d75240ee_258b_420a_b571_2b97dcda8a66 ol").append('<li> Menu 5 </li>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ctl00_g_d75240ee_258b_420a_b571_2b97dcda8a66">

  <ol class="top-menu-bar pull-right">
    <li>
      <a id="ctl00_g_d75240ee_258b_420a_b571_2b97dcda8a66_lbLanguage" href="/ar/">Test</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="ctl00_g_d75240ee_258b_420a_b571_2b97dcda8a66_lbSitemap" href="/en/sitemap">Sitemap</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="ctl00_g_d75240ee_258b_420a_b571_2b97dcda8a66_lbContact" href="/en/contact-us?tab=2">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a id="ctl00_g_d75240ee_258b_420a_b571_2b97dcda8a66_lbFaq" href="/en/contact-us?tab=3">FAQ</a>
    </li>
  </ol>

</div>
```

Comment: @user788592 : glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [After()](http://api.jquery.com/after/) method of JQuery:

```
$("#ctl00_g_d75240ee_258b_420a_b571_2b97dcda8a66  li").last().after('<li> Menu 5 </li>');
```

Here is [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9mm5wqkf/) for that.